# Add a value to a Text='<%# Bind("txt_case_num") %>

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms

Here is my entire web form so you can see what I have done. I want to be able to put the value of generatePassword(6) into the: InsertCommand="INSERT INTO utcasesTest(created_by_user_id, status_id, criticality_id, project_id, case_num, ... field in my db table.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
'Our Function generatePassword accepts one parameter 'passwordLength'
'passwordLength will obviously determine the password length.
'The aplhanumeric character set is assigned to the variable sDefaultChars
Function generatePassword(passwordLength)

  'Declare variables
   Dim sDefaultChars
   Dim iCounter
   Dim sMyPassword
   Dim iPickedChar
   Dim iDefaultCharactersLength
   Dim iPasswordLength

   'Initialize variables
   sDefaultChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ0123456789"
   iPasswordLength = passwordLength
   iDefaultCharactersLength = Len(sDefaultChars)
   Randomize() 'initialize the random number generator

   'Loop for the number of characters password is to have
   For iCounter = 1 To iPasswordLength
      'Next pick a number from 1 to length of character set 
      iPickedChar = Int((iDefaultCharactersLength * Rnd) + 1)

      'Next pick a character from the character set using the random number iPickedChar
      'and Mid function
       sMyPassword = sMyPassword & Mid(sDefaultChars, iPickedChar, 1)
   Next

   generatePassword = sMyPassword
End Function
</script>

<script runat="server" type="text/vb">
Sub FormView1_Item_Inserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormViewInsertedEventArgs)

    Response.Redirect("ThankYou.asp")
End Sub

Protected Sub FormView1_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewPageEventArgs)

End Sub

Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Selecting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs)

End Sub
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
  .style1 
  {
      width: 100%;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Input Form-->
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
  <div>
    <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" 
                  DataKeyNames="case_id"
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_OC" 
                  DefaultMode="Insert" 
                  OnItemInserted="formview1_Item_Inserted"
                  onpageindexchanging="FormView1_PageIndexChanging">
      <InsertItemTemplate>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>criticality_id:</td>
            <td>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="criticality_idTextBox" 
                                runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("txt_criticality_id","{0:D}") %>' 
                                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_Criticality" 
                                DataTextField="ut_value"
                                DataValueField="criticality_id"
                                AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" 
                              Text="--Select Level--" 
                              Selected="True" />
              </asp:DropDownList>
              <br />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>case_num:</td>
            <td>
              <asp:TextBox Name="txt_case_num" 
                           ID="case_numTextBox" 
                           runat="server"
                           Text='<%# Bind("txt_case_num") %>' /> **<------ This is the textbox the value needs to go into. It will be hidden so the user wont see it**
              <br />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>title:</td>
            <td>
              <asp:TextBox ID="titleTextBox" 
                           runat="server" 
                           Text='<%# Bind("txt_title") %>' />
              <br />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>description:</td>
            <td>
              <asp:TextBox ID="descriptionTextBox" 
                           runat="server" 
                           Text='<%# Bind("txt_description") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" />
              <br />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>external_email_address:</td>
            <td>    
              <asp:TextBox ID="external_email_addressTextBox" 
                           runat="server"
                           Text='<%# Bind("txt_external_email_address") %>' />
              <br />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" 
                        runat="server" 
                        CausesValidation="True"
                        CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" 
                              runat="server" 
                              CausesValidation="False" 
                              CommandName="Cancel" 
                              Text="Cancel" />
      </InsertItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
    <!--Datasource-->
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_OC" 
                       runat="server"
                       ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OC_ConnectionString %>" 
                       InsertCommand="INSERT INTO utcasesTest(created_by_user_id, status_id, criticality_id, project_id, case_num, is_active, description, title, created_by_timestamp, modified_by_timestamp, modified_by_user_id, is_external, external_email_address, object_id, object_type_id) VALUES (@txt_created_by_user_id, @txt_status_id, @txt_criticality_id, @txt_project_id, @txt_case_num, @txt_case_num  **<-------This is where the value is passed to the DB**, @txt_description, @txt_title, getdate(), getdate(), @txt_modified_by_user_id, @txt_is_external, @txt_external_email_address, @txt_object_id, @txt_object_type_id)" 
                       SelectCommand="SELECT utcasesTest.* FROM utcasesTest">
      <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="txt_created_by_user_id" DefaultValue="1" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="txt_status_id" DefaultValue="1" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="txt_criticality_id" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="txt_project_id" DefaultValue="1" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="txt_case_num" />  **<----------Paramater Definition**
        <asp:Parameter Name="txt_is_active" DefaultValue="Y" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="txt_description" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="txt_title" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="txt_created_by_timestamp" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="txt_modified_by_timestamp" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="txt_modified_by_user_id" DefaultValue="1" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="txt_is_external" DefaultValue="Y" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="txt_external_email_address" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="txt_object_id" DefaultValue="-1" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="txt_object_type_id" DefaultValue="-1" />
      </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <!--Data source for criticallity dropdown-->
    <!--Change Project ID to select criticality from right Binder: id 3 = GNRM-->
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_Criticality" 
                       runat="server" 
                       ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OCConnectionString_utcriticality %>" 
                       SelectCommand="SELECT project_id, ut_value, criticality_id FROM utcriticality WHERE (project_id = 3)" 
                       onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <!--End data source for criticallity dropdown-->
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your insert code?  By the way, I'd suggest looking into learning how to use code-behind.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but something like this might work (if I'm reading your comments correctly):  `Text='<%# Bind(generatPassword(Eval("txt_case_num"))) %>'`

Comment: I get:Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: A call to Bind was not well formatted.  Please refer to documentation for the correct parameters to Bind.

Source Error: 


Line 96:             <td>
Line 97:                 
Line 98:                <asp:TextBox Name="txt_case_num" ID="case_numTextBox" runat="server" 
Line 99:                     Text='<%# Bind(generatPassword(Eval("txt_case_num"))) %>' />
Line 100: